# Permissions Error while creating native module for react native

Tags: java

I am getting this error while creating native module. Please let me know how i can solve this

Exception in native call

java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field 'android.os.MessageQueue android.os.Looper.mQueue' on a null object reference in method 'void android.os.Handler.(android.os.Looper, android.os.Handler$Callback, boolean)'

at android.os.Handler.(Handler.java:257)

at android.os.Handler.(Handler.java:162)

at android.telephony.PhoneStateListener.(PhoneStateListener.java:569)

at android.telephony.PhoneStateListener.(PhoneStateListener.java:534)

at com.vt.connectoverseasapp.CallDetectorModule$CustomPhoneStateListener.(CallDetectorModule.java:33)

at com.vt.connectoverseasapp.CallDetectorModule$CustomPhoneStateListener.(Unknown Source:0)

at com.vt.connectoverseasapp.CallDetectorModule.(CallDetectorModule.java:24)

at com.vt.connectoverseasapp.MyReactPackage.createNativeModules(MyReactPackage.java:16)

at com.facebook.react.ReactPackageHelper.getNativeModuleIterator(ReactPackageHelper.java:42)

at com.facebook.react.NativeModuleRegistryBuilder.processPackage(NativeModuleRegistryBuilder.java:42)

at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager.processPackage(ReactInstanceManager.java:1467)

at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager.processPackages(ReactInstanceManager.java:1438)

at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager.createReactContext(ReactInstanceManager.java:1340)

at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager.-$$Nest$mcreateReactContext(Unknown Source:0)

at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager$5.run(ReactInstanceManager.java:1111)

at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1012)

I don't have any experience in JAVA so i just got this code from Chat gpt